# If $\lvert \int fa \rvert, \lvert \int gb \rvert \geq \alpha$, what about $\lvert \int fgab \rvert+\lvert \int fgb \rvert+\lvert \int fga \rvert$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

In the course of a project, I'd like to prove or disprove the following statement: let $f,g$ and $a,b$ be real-valued functions defined say on $\mathbb{R}$, and $\alpha > 0$ such that $\lvert \int_\mathbb{R} fa \rvert \geq \alpha$ and $\lvert \int_\mathbb{R} gb \rvert \geq \alpha$; and $\int_\mathbb{R} ab = 0.$ Is there any non-trivial (that is, positive, and function of $\alpha$) lower bound that one can prove on
$$\left\lvert \int_\mathbb{R} fgab \right\rvert+\left\lvert \int_\mathbb{R} fgb \right\rvert+\left\lvert \int_\mathbb{R} fga \right\rvert\;?$$
 (or, equivalently, on at least one of the 3 terms)

Thank you,

-- Clément

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, let $a=f=1_{[0,1]}, b=g=1_{[2,3]}$. Then $\int f a = 1, \int gb = 1$, $\int a b = 0$ and, since $fg=0$, the quantity above is zero.

Comment: Thanks -- so this formulation does not capture what I would need.